# how to count a list of image tag inside a parent div and then remove some from certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am producing an image tag `<img>` inside div dynamically from database by `fetching`. My html looks like below :-

```
 <div class='forimgbox'>

       <p class='palheading'>Pals</p>

       <img src='userpic/2232323.png'  width='80px' height='100px'>
       <img src='userpic/44542.png'  width='80px' height='100px'>   
       <img src='userpic/88282.png'  width='80px' height='100px'>
       <img src='userpic/67788.png'  width='80px' height='100px'>
       <img src='userpic/567886.png'  width='80px' height='100px'>
       <img src='userpic/456788.png'  width='80px' height='100px'>
       <img src='userpic/355667.png'  width='80px' height='100px'>

 </div>
```

Now the thing what I wanna do is I want to remove some `<img>` tag from that parent div by using jquery.I wanna make that jquery works like that it keep '6' `<img>` starting from top and then remove or delete every `<img>` tag which are produced after 6th `<img>` tag from database.Can we do that guys?I thought that it is possible like counting the number of `<img>` tag of that parent `div` and remove every `<img>` tag after '6th' `<img>` tag.Please help needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:gt()` selector for that,

```
$(".forimgbox img:gt(5)").remove();
```

It is an index based approach, :gt(5) selector will select all the elements with index greater than 5.(note that, index are counting from 0).

Comment: In one shot bro your code did my work.Really appreciate your answer bro thanks.

Comment: Always welcome bro. So you can accept my answer. Right?

Comment: ya i was in hurry but it takes 5min still so..wait i will do for sure ;)

Answer (score 1):

for calculate length :

```
console.log($(".forimgbox img").length)
```

for remove

```
$(".forimgbox img:gt(5)").remove()
```

[here the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63vhjz9z/1/)

Comment: Why you are using loop for this?

Comment: to remove every image after 6th image

Comment: $(".forimgbox img:gt(5)").remove(); will do the stuff. no need for loop here

Comment: oh.. it's work magically,i got your point i have updated both fiddle and answer thanks